# How to display LinearProgressIndicator in a Row with Text

Tags: dart, flutter

I want to use a `Row` to display some `Text` then the `LinearProgressIndicator` in a row, using this code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {   @override   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'MaterialApp',
      home: Scaffold(
          body: SafeArea(child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text('Start row'),
              LinearProgressIndicator(),
            ],
          ),)),
    );   } }
```

The problem is nothing is displayed when I wrap the `Text` and the `LinearProgressIndicator` in a `Row`.

I can only get the `Row` to display the `Text` when I delete `LinearProgressIndicator`. And I can only get the `LinearProgressIndicator`  to display when the `Row` is not used like this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'MaterialApp',
      home: Scaffold(
          body: SafeArea(child: LinearProgressIndicator(),)),
    );
  }
}
```

This is what the app looks like without the `Row`.

[image: without row]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should set a width for LinearProgressIndicator widget when it's inside a row widget. the error in console explained it very clear:

> BoxConstraints forces an infinite width.
>   These invalid constraints were provided to RenderCustomPaint's layout() function by the following
>   function, which probably computed the invalid constraints in question:

Every unbounded widget should be wrapped inside widgets like Expanded or Flexible:

In this case:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'MaterialApp',
      home: Scaffold(
          body: SafeArea(
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Center( // this widget is not nessesary
              child: Text('Some text'),
            ),
            Expanded(child: LinearProgressIndicator()),
          ],
        ),
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

There is also a [discussion here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/9780) related to this matter.